# getJSON() call to Web API hosted in Azure fails

Tags: json, azure

I am hosting a demo Web Api in Azure:

http://loungewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/customer/

It works on browser, and all web based testing pages, in Fiddler etc. But it does not work from my HTML/JavaScript page. Established API calls such as: http://ip.jsontest.com/ do work fine. What is going with my API call at Azure that will work everywhere except from my page?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Send an AJAX request
        $.getJSON("http://loungewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/customer/")
            .done(function (data) {

                // On success, 'data' contains a list of customers
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    alert("success");
                });
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert("status: " + status);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Please define: "does not work".  Do you get your alert with the status?  Does the console log anything?  What does the network tab of <insert web dev tools of your favourite browser here> say?

Comment: It goes to the .fail() function (it does not go into .done()). Status just states "error". The json return by my API is valid, as tested in web pages for this purpose. The thing I can't get a proper error message, where I can understand why is it failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely what is not working is that you haven't enabled CORS on your Web API to access it properly.

Check [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for instructions how to enable it and then try again. Also, as other mentioned, some extra information will be good if what I described is not the case.

Comment: Yes sir, this did the trick! I'm new to Web API and didn't knew about CORS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked. It's not really a WebAPI thing per se, more here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Also, in the future to help you debug those things easier, consider using Fiddler so you can see the request/response from the calls as they happen. You can do the same on Chrome's Dev Tools but Fiddler is more detailed/feature complete.